# When to use CREATE INDEX and when to use USE INDEX

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite

I am using SQLite in an Android application that should stores thousands of sound Tracks. I have decided to use the Track_title as an INDEX for faster selection and search. After a long reading session I have understood from  this source [LINK](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_indexes.htm) that the INDEX will make the `SELECT` faster but will make the `INSERT` slower. They recommend to drop the `index` from the table before the insertion of big data and re-put it again after it. 
Using this syntax:

```
CREATE INDEX my_idx ON my_table (my_attribute);
```

Some other sources, recommended to use `index` while performing the `select` query not on the Creation of the `TABLE` from this [LINK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html). using this syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table USE INDEX (col1)
WHERE col1= name;
```

The Question is: Which one of those methods will give me better performance? and what is the Advantages and disadvantages of both?

Comment: your index does nothing as it is not related to the query. Usually, index use is automatic based on he where clause.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the two commands, they are not synonymous. You cannot use `USE INDEX` without first creating it (with `CREATE INDEX`). You should use `USE INDEX` (with care) when the optimiser is not using a certain index that will in fact aid query execution, and you want to force the use of this index.

Comment: SQLite is not MySQL so don't look at MySQL documents. You can't do `USE INDEX` in SQLite.

Comment: No @JakubKania, All the references says that we can use `INDEX` in `SQLite` .. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_indexes.htm

Comment: If you are doing a lot of inserts one after the other, wrap the process in a transaction for better performance (and to allow rollback if a statement fails). As to whether drop/re-create is worthwhile, do a performance test - log start and end times to see if it's worth doing.

Comment: @AbdEl-RahmanEl-Tamawy No.There is no `USE INDEX` command in SQLite. There are indexes but that command doesn't exist. There is `INDEXED BY` command which works similar but still it is different.

Comment: @JakubKania, do you recommend to use `INDEXED BY` rather than `CREATE INDEX`?

Comment: @AbdEl-RahmanEl-Tamawy : again, you are mistaking both commands. Create index creates an index that you can use later, either implicitly (most of the time) or explicitly using Use index or Indexed by.

Comment: just create an index for the column you use most often in your where clauses, write you where clauses so that this column is first in the query, and let the database server decide when to use the index.

Answer (score 1):

The two are not incompatible.  You cannot *use* an index unless it is already created.

Your table is pretty small, with just a few thousand rows.  I would not worry about table creation performance, unless you specifically experience that.

An index works like the index at the end of a book.  If you want to find a particular title, the engine can quickly scan the index and determine which data records contain that title.  This does come with an overhead when data is being inserted/updated/deleted in the table, because the index has to be maintained.

This can be a big performance issue, when inserting millions of rows into a table, particularly an empty table.  That is the situation where you want to drop the index and then add it again after the data is in the table.  The idea is that the engine can create the index faster than it can insert one row after another.

One final note.  A query typically uses an index when the columns in the index are being referenced in the `on`, `where`, or `order by`.  In your example, the index contains a column called `my_attribute` but the query references `col1`.  The index would not be used for this query.

Comment: For sure I will use `my_attribute` in the select query. `col` is just an example. Thats why I wanted to use index on it. What is your final recommendation for my issue?

Comment: If you are experiencing performance problems, add the indexes needed to make the queries work.  Don't worry about inserts/updates, unless you experience performance problems there too.